# Android Studio Not Showing Changes

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm developing an application in Android Studio, but when I make changes to the GUI there are no changes being shown once I run the application on the device.

I've tried:

1. Rebuilding
2. Disabling instant-run
3. Updating AndroidStudio
4. Uninstalling the Application from the device upon each new deployment

Any ideas?

---code---

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/homeTitle"
    android:id="@+id/titleText"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/enableSwitch"
    android:text="@string/enableString"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titleText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/brightness_string"
    android:id="@+id/brightnessSwitch"
    android:layout_below="@+id/enableSwitch"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp" />

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/gpsManagementString"
    android:id="@+id/gpsSwitch"
    android:layout_below="@+id/brightnessSwitch"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp" />

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/commsManagementString"
    android:id="@+id/commsSwitch"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gpsSwitch"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="135dp"
    android:text="@string/options_string"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="135dp"
    android:text="@string/about_string"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Comment: Well what are those changes?

Comment: Currently I'm only trying to make a UI in the XML but it looks like no matter what I'm changing it isn't being displayed

Comment: You have to add the relevant information and code snippets into your post otherwise this will be closed soon.

Comment: try to Clean and Rebuild and if id did not work try File/invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Tried both of those now @AtefHares, didn't work. I'm going to update AS to the most recent version

Answer (score 0):

First On the main menu, choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.

Second Try Refresh Layout

Third find Error in the Layout pan and try to fix it.

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling instant run :
Goto : File> settings > build > execution > deployment > InstantRun and disable it.
It worked for me